# Problems with heroku toolbelt

Tags: ruby, heroku, rubygems, installation, rvm

I'm absolute newbie in Ruby and Rails project, so I'm sorry if this is dumb question.

I've installed heroku toolbelt using `wget -qO- https://toolbelt.heroku.com/install-ubuntu.sh | sh`. Also I tried `gem install heroku`. But when I type:

```
MY_USER@home-PC:~$ heroku version
<internal:gem_prelude>:1:in `require': cannot load such file -- rubygems.rb (LoadError)
    from <internal:gem_prelude>:1:in `<compiled>'
```

I've checked in google and people suggest that gem and current ruby are different versions so I've checked it and they seem to the same:

```
MY_USER@home-PC:~$ which ruby
/home/MY_USER/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p327/bin/ruby

MY_USER@home-PC:~$ gem env | grep 'RUBY EXECUTABLE'
  - RUBY EXECUTABLE: /home/MY_USER/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p327/bin/ruby
```

I have no idea what to do more, so please help.

Sorry for the maybe stupid question, thanks in advance.

EDIT: 
Forgot to say I'm running Ubuntu 12.10.

Comment: Try running ``ruby `which heroku` version``..what happens then? Note the backticks around `which heroku`.

Comment: `MY_USER@home-PC:~$ ruby \`which heroku\` version` returns: 
`heroku-toolbelt/2.33.1 (i686-linux) ruby/1.9.3`

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The problem is that the `heroku` executable you installed probably starts with a line like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby
```

This will force the `heroku` command to always use the system-wide ruby (`/usr/bin/ruby`) and it will never run your rvm version of ruby.

To fix it simply edit the first line of the `heroku` script to this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
```

This will make the `heroku` command run whichever ruby command is in the current `PATH`, instead of a hard coded path like previously.

To find the location of the `heroku` script, so you can edit it, simply type:

```
which heroku
```

It should print out the location of the script so you can find it and load it into your editor.

Comment: Thank you, I fully understand what you mean but `\`whick hereku\`` returns the same error `<internal:gem_prelude>:1:in \`require\': cannot load such file -- rubygems.rb (LoadError) from <internal:gem_prelude>:1:in `<compiled>'`.
So I search the file in Nautilus and found `heroku` file in `/usr/local/heroku/bin`, which first line is `#!/usr/bin/env ruby1.9.1`. I've changed it to `#!/usr/bin/env ruby`, which seems to work for now. Thank you very, very much, now I can try to learn this language. Thanks again!

Comment: @erik1001 Ok. Thanks and sorry my bad. I edited the answer (`which heroku` should have been run without the backticks). But good that you managed to figure it out anyway. Good luck with ruby.

Comment: Sometimes, the first line may be instead something like `/usr/bin/env ruby1.9.1`, (including `env` in it already) but still editing it to `/usr/bin/env ruby` (just plain `ruby` and no version) should make it work with rvm.

Answer (score 0):

Also if you do not have write permission you may enter:

```
:w !sudo tee % > /dev/null
```

to save successfully .